# Enable zoom in and out on touchpad

Tags: 11.04, thinkpad

I can use the touchpad scrolling with two fingers. 
The os is Natty and my laptop is a Thinkpad x220.
But the touchpad doesn't support zoom in and out.
Any suggestion?

Comment: The only way you can get this is to have hardware that supports it.